# Migration of Realm for Android: how to addRealmListField correctly

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

In the previous RealmDB, I have Program table like:

```
public class Program extends RealmObject {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("episodes")
    @ParcelPropertyConverter(RealmListParcelConverter.class)
    public RealmList<Episode> episodes;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("performers")
    @Ignore
    public List<Performer> performers;
}
```

And Performer table:

```
public class Performer {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    public Long id;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

}
```

In new version, I want to add performers attribute to database. So I implemented Migration like this:
In MyApplication:

```
private void initRealm() {
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                .Builder()
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new OnsMigration())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }
```

and OnsMigration class:

```
public class OnsMigration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        if (newVersion == 1) {
            RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
            RealmObjectSchema performerSchema = schema.create("Performer")
                    .addField("id", Long.class)
                    .addField("name", String.class)
            RealmObjectSchema programSchema = schema.get("Program");
            programSchema.addRealmListField("performers", performerSchema);
        }
    }
}
```

But program.getPerformers() still be Null.
How to customize Migration correctly ?
Thank you

Comment: I assume the fact that `List` should be `RealmList`, and the `@Ignore` should be removed

Comment: And of course `Performer` should be `extends RealmObject`

Comment: I face other error: "RuntimeException: Unable to create application: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class already exists: Performer"

Comment: Try to use `oldVersion == 0` instead of `newVersion == 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if the class "Performer" already exists.

```java
public class OnsMigration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        if (newVersion == 1) {
            RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
        if(!schema.contains("Performer"){ // Check if the class already exists.
            RealmObjectSchema performerSchema = schema.create("Performer")
                    .addField("id", Long.class)
                    .addField("name", String.class)
            RealmObjectSchema programSchema = schema.get("Program");
            programSchema.addRealmListField("performers", performerSchema);
           }
        }
    }
}
```